# Making an exact date for the arrival of Moshiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, messianic-redemption

Is it the Ramban or Rambam that forbade one from making an attempt to figure an exact date for the arrival of Moshiach?

Comment: the Gemara in Sanhedrin

Comment: Also the torah forbids so on a more general note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rambam writes in [Hilkhot Melakhim (12:5)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e512.htm) that a person shouldnt reckon the time of the messiah's arrival:

> ולעולם לא יתעסק אדם בדברי ההגדות, ולא יאריך בדברי מדרשות האמורים בעניינים אלו וכיוצא בהן...--שאינן מביאין לא לידי אהבה, ולא לידי יראה.  **וכן לא יחשב הקיצין; אמרו חכמים, תפוח דעתן של מחשבי קיצין.  אלא יחכה ויאמין בכלל הדבר**, כמו שביארנו
>
> A person should always avoid involving himself in the words of the aggadot and should not spend much time on the words of midrashim that are said in these [eschatological predictions] for they bring to neither love or fear [of God]. And similarly a person shouldn't calculate messianic times. The sages said (cf. [Sanhedrin 97b](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.97b?lang=bi)) 'May the minds of those who attempt to determine the time of the messiah's coming expire'. Rather one should wait and believe in the general idea [of the messiah].

He writes similarly in his [commentary to Sanhedrin (10:1)](http://www.sefaria.org/Rambam_on_Mishnah_Sanhedrin.10.1?lang=bi):

> ואין לקבוע לו זמן, ולא לפרש את המקראות כדי להוציא מהן זמן בואו, אמרו חכמים תפוח דעתן של מחשבי קצין.
>
> One should not set a time for the messiah's arrival, not should one explain the verses to derive from them the time of his arrival. The sages said: ''May the minds of those who attempt to determine the time of the messiah's coming expire'.

Comment: Can you send me a link to his commentary?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah done. Scroll down to the bold words the twelfth principle.

Answer (score 1):

The Rambam in his *iggeret teiman* cites the gemara in Sanhedrin 97 that curses those who calculate the time of the eschaton.

Comment: and then offers his prediction in iggeret hashmad!