# What is the exact date of the end of days referenced in the book of Daniel according to various commentators?

Tags: daniel-book-of, ymoth-hamoshiach, calculation

According to [this article](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2705100/jewish/Can-I-Calculate-the-Date-of-Moshiachs-Arrival.htm) many commentators starting from the time of Rebbeynu Saadia Gaon through the time of the Alter Rebbi used the pesukim in the book of Daniel to calculate when the end of days will be. I would like to know what date (Hebrew or secular) each calculation arrives at for at least the following (preferably more)

- Rambam
- Ramban
- Rashi
- Abravanel
- Arizal
- Vilna Gaon
- Alter Rebbi

Comment: I think you're misreading the article. It says "_[t]hroughout our long exile, many of our greatest sages have calculated the date of Moshiach’s arrival_", and lists their names, but does not say that they all did so using the pesukim in the book of Daniel. In fact, in the case of Rambam, it says: "_Similarly, Maimonides, in his Iggeret Teiman_ ... _presents a date **passed on to him by his ancestors**_" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @TamirEvan thanks, I believe the date Rambam gives is based on his ancestors interpretation of the pesukim in Daniel.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81098/making-an-exact-date-for-the-arrival-of-moshiach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: Many views were collected in this table [here](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%A7%D7%A5_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA).

**Rambam** - In Iggeret Teiman he [wrote](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Iggerot_HaRambam%2C_Iggeret_Teiman.12?vhe=Kobetz_Teshuvot_HaRambam,_1859&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en): "...תחזור הנבואה לישראל בשנת ארבעה אלפים תתקע"ו ליצירה..." - Year 4976 which is 1216 CE. But that's the year of *prophecy returning*. He doesn't give a date for the Meshiach, which will be not long after the return of prophecy, according to him. And as noted by @TamirEvan, he doesn't give this calculation according to Daniel.

**Ramban** - According to his [commentary on Beresheet 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.2.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Ramban_on_Genesis.2.3.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) and based on Daniel 12:11, it'll be in the year 5118 which is 1357/8 CE.

**Rashi** - According to his [commentary on Daniel 8:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.8.14?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Daniel.8.14.2&lang2=bi), the Mashiach will come 1290 years after the destruction of the Second Temple per the Jewish dating, which is 68 CE, therefore he'll come in 5118 which 1357/8 CE (like Ramban).

**Abarbanel** - According to [Maayan 12, Tamar 2-3](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23900&pgnum=158) in his book Maayanei Hayeshuah, it'll be in the year 5291 which is 1530/1 CE (for some reason the table linked above has it as 5294/1534. Might be a typo or another version of the book).

**Ari** - In his commentary on the Torah "Likutei Torah", Miketz (pg. 119 [here](https://ha-zohar.net/BOOKS/ETZCHAYIM14-H.pdf)) he writes that the Geulah will be in the year 5736 which is the year 1976 CE.

**Vilna Gaon** - According to Rabbi Ouri Cherki [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIx2kCDhSpk), the Vilna Gaon in [his commentary on Sifra De'Tzniuta](http://www.hebrew.grimoar.cz/zohar/gra_sifra.htm) calculated that the Geulah will happen in the year 5708 which is 1948 CE.

**Alter Rebbi** - According to [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A5_(%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA)#%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%9F) (using the same source as the Chabad article), the date is 5603 which is 1842/3 CE.

**Malbim** - According to his [commentary on Daniel 8:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Daniel.8.14?lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_Daniel.8.14.1&lang2=bi), there are two possible dates: 5673 - 1913 CE or 5688 - 1928 CE.

Comment: You might want to add that many sources speak of the *geula* arriving step by step, as such the dates above might start the beginning of the process. See many sources in chapter 1 [here](https://machon.oretzion.com/document/step%20by%20step%20example.pdf)